# Joining SQL Tables and display columns as rows to generate a report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

i have three tables related to each other explained below

```
Contacts
====================================================================================
ContactID           ContactName

1               Contact 1               
2               Contact 2
3               Contact 3
4               Contact 4
5               Contact 5


Questions
=====================================================================================
QuestionID          QuestionText

1               What is your Department?
2               Would you be interested in attending this year show?
3               Number of Employees in your company?


Answers
======================================================================================
QuestionID          ContactID           AnswerText

1                   1                   IT
1                   2                   HR
3                   4                   60
2                   2                   Yes
```

i would like to generate a report in below format

```
Report
====================================================================================================================================================

ContactID   What is your Department?    Would you be interested in attending this year show?        Number of Employees in your company?


1           IT                  NULL                                NULL
2           HR                  Yes                             NULL
4           NULL                    NULL                                60
```

is there a way to generate a dynamic report using T-SQL, I tried using pivot but most of the samples on the internet is using only one table and limited fields. any help or right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
-- you columns
Declare @cols nvarchar(max);
Set @cols = STUFF((Select distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(QuestionText) 
            From #Questions FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

-- dynamic query
Declare @sql nvarchar(max);
Set @sql = '
    Select * 
    From (
        Select a.ContactID, a.AnswerText, q.QuestionText From #Questions q
        Inner Join #Answers a On a.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
    ) as x
    Pivot (
        MAX(AnswerText)
        For QuestionText in ('+@cols+')
    ) as piv
';

-- execute the dynamic query
--print @sql;
Exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

When you write a Pivot query, it is best to use a subquery (X here) or a CTE. This will be used to join your data and return only the 3 rows required by the pivot.

@cols is used to get a list of your columns:  `[Number of Employees in your company?], [What is your Department?], [Would you be interested in attending this year show?]`

This is added to the @sql variable. It contains the main query which will be executed with `sp_executesql`.

**Output:**

```
ContactID   What is your Department?    Would you be interested in attending this year show?    Number of Employees in your company?
1           IT                          NULL                                                    NULL
2           HR                          Yes                                                     NULL
4           NULL                        NULL                                                    60
```

**Your data:**

```
Declare table #Questions(QuestionID int, QuestionText varchar(100))
Insert into @Questions(QuestionID, QuestionText) values
    (1, 'What is your Department?')
    , (2, 'Would you be interested in attending this year show?')
    , (3, 'Number of Employees in your company?')

Declare table #Answers(QuestionID int, ContactID int, AnswerText varchar(10))
Insert into @Answers(QuestionID, ContactID, AnswerText) values 
    (1, 1, 'IT')
    , (1, 2, 'HR')
    , (3, 4, '60')
    , (2, 2, 'Yes')
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but I am looking for a dynamic solution, in your solution questions are hardcoded. but you have shown me a direction at least. cheers

Comment: thanks mate, updated answer is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I have created the column names are dynamically with the help of this [link](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/). Added the in-line comments for the queries

```
-- Declare Variables
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column, here QuestionText
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(QuestionText)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT QuestionText FROM #Questions) AS QText
-- SELECT @ColumnName

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N' 
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT ANS.ContactID, ANS.AnswerText, QUE.QuestionText
    FROM #Questions QUE
    INNER JOIN #Answers ANS ON ANS.QuestionID = QUE.QuestionID
) AS T
PIVOT (
    MAX(AnswerText)
    FOR QuestionText IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
) AS PVTTable'

-- Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

The temporary table creations are:

```
CREATE  TABLE #Contacts(ContactID INT, ContactName VARCHAR (50))
CREATE  TABLE #Questions( QuestionID INT, QuestionText VARCHAR(100))
CREATE  TABLE #Answers(QuestionID INT, ContactID INT, AnswerText VARCHAR (100))

INSERT INTO #Contacts
SELECT 1, 'Contact 1' UNION SELECT             
2, 'Contact 2' UNION SELECT
3, 'Contact 3' UNION SELECT
4, 'Contact 4' UNION SELECT
5, 'Contact 5'

INSERT INTO #Questions
SELECT 1 , 'What is your Department?' UNION SELECT 
2 , 'Would you be interested in attending this year show?' UNION SELECT 
3 , 'Number of Employees in your company?' 

INSERT INTO #Answers
SELECT 1, 1 , 'IT' UNION SELECT  
1, 2 , 'HR' UNION SELECT  
3, 4 , '60' UNION SELECT  
2, 2 , 'Yes'
```

DROP The temporary tables:

```
DROP TABLE #Answers
DROP TABLE #Contacts
DROP TABLE #Questions
```